# Given a unicode error I don't understand

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

Here is my code, I'm sure it looks terrible but it all works as it should, only problem I'm having is with the last line...

```
import pyPdf
import os
import csv

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)


    PDFWriter = csv.writer(open('/home/nick/TAM_work/text/text.doc', 'a'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    def getPDFContent(path):
        content = ""
        # Load PDF into pyPDF
        pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
        # Iterate pages
        for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
            # Extract text from page and add to content
            content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
        # Collapse whitespace
        content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
        return content

    for word in os.listdir("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs"):
     print getPDFContent("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs/" + word)

    PDFWriter.writerow ([getPDFContent("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs/" + word)])
```

When I run it everything works until it hits this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Saving_fuction_added.py", line 52, in <module>
    PDFWriter.writerow ([getPDFContent("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs/" + word)])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 81: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'd love any help. Thanks guys.

Matt

Comment: Do you have non-ascii filenames?  I'm confused because the stacktrace is so short - it seems to indicate the error is within the list-comprehension (TAM_pdfs+word), not within the writerow() function?

Comment: I thought that too at first, but then wouldn't it fail on the previous line?

Comment: Tried changing my .doc to a .csv and adding
    try:
    x = unicode(value, "ascii")
except UnicodeError:
    value = unicode(value, "utf-8")
else:
    # value was valid ASCII data
    pass
But that didn't work.
Maybe I'm looking at this the totally wrong way? I just need to get the text I extract to a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that answered that question. But now it only writes the last file.

```
  import pyPdf
import os
import csv

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)


PDFWriter = csv.writer(open('/home/nick/TAM_work/text/text.doc', 'a'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    # Collapse whitespace
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content

for word in os.listdir("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs"):
    print getPDFContent("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs/" + word)

PDFWriter.writerow ([getPDFContent("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs/" + word).encode("ascii", "ignore")])
```

Comment: fixed again by bring the 
    PDFWriter.writerow ([getPDFContent("/home/nick/TAM_work/TAM_pdfs/" + word).encode("ascii", "ignore")])

into the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

as I Underestand you put a large number in a small varible and its throw an exception.

I introduce you a C# tool that work very fine with unicode , you can find it at http://unicode.codeplex.com

in your case I recommand to change the

```
 for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
```

pdf.getNumPages() is above than 128 just controll it.

Comment: -1 The OP's exception was a UnicodeEncodeError which only vaguely could be characterised as "large number in small variable" and is definitely nothing to do with the number of pages in the PDF file. As for your undocumented "tool", you'd have to convince a Python user that it provided something on top of Python's standard unicode facilities -- but please don't take these remarks as an invitation to further spamming, quite the contrary.